# Query for branch numbers with no salesperson

Tags: sql, database

I am having following four tables :

```
EMPLOYEE
PK: employeeID;     
FK: empBranch references BRANCH;
FK: empSupervisor references EMPLOYEE
```

[image]

```
BRANCH
PK: branchNumber
FK: branchManager references EMPLOYEE
```

[image]

```
CUSTOMER
PK: customerID
```

[image]

```
ORDERS
PK: orderNumber
FK: customerID references CUSTOMER; 
FK: salesPerson references EMPLOYEE
```

[image]

I was making a project and got stuck in between. Can someone help me how to list out  the branch numbers for branches that have no salespersons working at the branch with ANY orders from customers located in the state in which the branch is located ?

I was trying to make query for it since two hours.Please help

Comment: @JenR Yes Orders are being delivered to customer with given customerID through salesperson

Comment: Please edit the question with your attempts.  Also, let us know if this is a homework problem.

Comment: Could you explain how the orders tie into the results you want?  I posted a "branches without salespeople" query below, but based on your description I think you might want something to do with the orders

Comment: @JenR This was not required. Actually see lets see customer c1 who is in Miami, he  is being dealed by salesperson e5 which is in branch2 that is also in Miami so this branchID won't be included

Comment: @JenR Branch 2 has e5,e6 as salesperson. Also branch 2 is located in Miami. Also e6 deals with customer c1 who is also in Miami. So we can't include it in resultset.
Then branch3 has e7,e8 as salesperson.But they don't deal with any customer in their located city. So include b3 in result. Similairly we can't include b4 because we have customer in New york

Comment: @JenR If you got it then do reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get the branches without salespeople, ignoring whether orders exist:

```
Select branchnumber
from branch
where branchnumber not in (Select empbranch from employee 
    where emptitle = 'salesperson')
```

Based on your clarification, I believe you want to know what branches haven't had any sales within their state. Start by getting the Salespeople based on the orders they have sold:

```
Select employeeid, empbranch
from employee
join orders on orders.salesperson = employee.employeeid
```

Now you know who sold something, narrow it down by state:

```
Select employeeid, empbranch
from employee
join orders on orders.salesperson = employee.employeeid
join customer on customer.customerid = orders.customerid 
join branch on employee.empbranch = branch.branchnumber 
    and branch.branchstate = customer.custstate
```

So now you've got only the employees that have sold something in their home state.  You need to flip that and get the branches that don't have orders sold by their own salespeople:

```
Select branchnumber
from branch
where branchid not in (
    select empbranch
    from employee
    join orders on orders.salesperson = employee.employeeid
    join customer on customer.customerid = orders.customerid 
    join branch on employee.empbranch = branch.branchnumber 
        and branch.branchstate = customer.custstate)
```

Comment: This was not required. Actually see lets see customer c1 who is in Miami, he  is being dealed by salesperson e5 which is in branch2 that is also in Miami so this branchID won't be included

Comment: @ho_dareago see changes

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the list of branch numbers that are having no orders from any of the customers of the same state being handled by any employee working at the branch.

```
;with Tbl as
(
    select C.CustState,O.CustomerID,O.SalesPerson,B.BranchState,B.BranchNumber
    from Orders O
    inner join Customer C on C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
    inner join Employee E on E.EmpId = O.SalesPerson
    inner join Branch B on E.EmpBranch = B.BranchNumber
)

select T1.BranchNumber 
from Tbl as T1 left outer join Tbl as T2 
on T1.CustomerID = T2.CustomerID and T2.BranchState = T2.CustState
where T2.CustomerID is null
```